# Using a hashmap instead of a 2d array for a grid, Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to even use a O(1) type hash for a grid instead of a 2D-Array in Javascript?

2d array version that you would have to loop over every node to find a value:

```
let gridArr = [
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
];
```

Not sure how you create a grid with a hash for O(1) lookup?

```
let gridObj = [
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
    {},
]
```

Is it possible to create a grid and have O(1) time and O(1) space complexity here?

Comment: JavaScript arrays are hashmaps kind of. Accessing a property in an array is `O(1)`. What do you try to do really?

Comment: use a flat array and some arithmetic.

Comment: @Konrad Thanks for the reply. I'm asking this because I had an interview question and the interviewer kept trying to say how would you make this grid into O(1), which is some sort of hash map, but I couldn't figure out what exactly he was trying to get me to say.. So I failed and now i'm really annoyed if this was even true or not..

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell exactly what the interview question was from your description, but O(1) coordinate space is standard in graphics programming. It works by converting between XY coordinates and a linear index.

```
const width = 100, height = 100;

const arrayLength = width * height;

const array = new Float32Array( arrayLength );

function getValueAt( x, y ) {
    const arrayIndex = x + y * width;
    return array[ arrayIndex ];
}
function setValueAt( x, y, value ) {
    const arrayIndex = x + y * width;
    array[ arrayIndex  ] = value;
}
```

If you just need to look up an item's location from a hash map... You just build a hash map of its coordinates.

```
const width = 100, height = 100;
const arrayLength = width * height;
const array = new Array( arrayLength );
const hashMap = new Map();

function getValueAt( x, y ) {
    const arrayIndex = x + y * width;
    return array[ arrayIndex ];
}
function setValueAt( x, y, value ) {
    const arrayIndex = x + y * width;
    array[ arrayIndex  ] = value;
    hashMap.set( value, { x, y } );
}
function getCoordinatesOfValue( value ) {
    return hashMap.get( value );
}
```